# MsgBox open if more than one selection in ListBox

Tags: vba, listbox

I have the following code that I thought would open a MsgBox warning if there is more than one selection made in ListBoxProjects.

However it opens the MsgBox if there is only one selection as well. It doesn't open the MsgBox if there are no selections. Bit stuck on this one, any help gratefully received.

```
If Me.ListBoxProjects.ListIndex > 1 Then
MsgBox "You can only edit Projects 1 at a time", vbExclamation, "Project Editing"
End If
```

Comment: google what is the `ListBox.ListIndex` property, and while you are doing that, find out what other properties are associated with the ListBox control

Answer (score 0):

`ListIndex` property returns the position of the selected item.
To achieve what you want you need you need to access the `ItemSelected` collection's `Count` property.

```
If ListBoxProjects.ItemsSelected.Count > 1 Then
  MsgBox "You can only edit Projects 1 at a time", vbExclamation, "Project Editing"
End If
```

Comment: I'm getting a Compile error: Method or data member not found on ".ItemsSelected"

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Selected` property array:

```
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then 
        ' do something

    End If
Next i
```